# The encryption information is unavailable. Try again. TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode8, testflight

The app is uploaded without errors, but when I press the install button I get this message:

[image]

I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12 and Xcode 8.

This has never happened to me in old versions of Xcode. What could be wrong?

Comment: I think it might be a temporary error, I also started getting it today.

Comment: I'm getting this as well (Xcode 7.3.1) but it's only appearing on one of my three test iOS devices. The other two are reporting "Unable to Download App... XXX could not be installed at this time." All of this suggests some kind of issue on the Apple/TestFlight side of things.

Comment: Another data point: Navigating to iTunes Connect > My Apps > [app] > TestFlight > TestFlight Builds iOS just spins - I'm not able to get a listing of my app's test builds.

Comment: I had to submit a new build late last night (10/25/16) to get it to work.  All I did was bump the build number.  Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TestFlight is currently unavailable, i can't either install from TestFlight or see any of my builds in Itunes Connect. Also my app was in processing for 4 hours, then this happened.

Please check here https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

[or this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmurG.png)

Update: Confirmed by Apple  [image: Here is the confirmation from Apple]

Comment: I'm not sure about this, because with other apps do not have that problem, I can install them without any inconvenience

Comment: I think this affects to apps that has being uploaded and processed for the past 6-8 hours and can't install for now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I never had an issue with setting or not setting the encryption flag. So I thought maybe they made a change today. So I added the key in and it still didn't work. I decided to remove the last build from testing then re-added it. That worked for me. I was immediately able to download and install the app. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Build another version and upload to Itunes Connect.
Maybe your time uploading have some problem from Apple Server.
I have just checked.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working for me this morning now. Incidentally Brad my app had  GPUImage embedded in it so just for giggles I also added the "App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption." switch to the embedded GPUImage plist. Not sure if that was relevant.