# Itunes Connect: won't let me get into the "Prepare for Submission" page

Tags: build, app-store-connect, itunes, submission

I just had my build complete processing and now it won't let me get into the "Prepare for Submission" page to submit the build.  I was on the "Prepare for Submission" page all morning waiting for the build to process.  Then, when it finally processes it wont let me back into the "Prepare Submission" page. I have asked Itunes support for help but that usually takes ages.

PLEASE HELP. Thanks.

*** I was able to get into the page about 8 hours later.  It must have just been a itunes connect error.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to - [The encryption information is unavailable. Try again. TestFlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226636/the-encryption-information-is-unavailable-try-again-testflight/40227733#40227733)

No builds are available and I'm also trying to submit my app but can't, Itunes connect is affected to.